# Can all operations on multiple elements in mathematics be reduced to binary operations?

Tags: binary-operations

To take a very simple example: imagine the sum 1 + 2 + 3 + 4. You can do this one step at a time: 1 + 2 = 3, then 3 + 3 = 6, then 6 + 4 = 10. It does not matter how long it takes you to move from one step to the next. The answer will always be the same. It is always a question with 3 operations, with each operation involving no more than two operands.

Are there any operations in mathematics that must be applied *at the same time* to more than two operands? Or is mathematics intrinsically a linear set of (unary and) binary operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classical result of Sierpinski is that every $n$-ary operation on a set is a finite composition of *binary* operations on the set, see W. Sierpinski, *Sur les fonctions de plusieurs variables,* Fund. Math. $\,33\, (1945),\, 169\!-\!173.$ See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116792/242) for further references.

The proof is quite  simple for operations on a finite set $\rm\,A.\,$  Namely, if $\rm\,|A| = n\,$ then we may encode $\rm\,A\,$ by $\rm\,\mathbb Z/n,\,$ the ring of integers $\rm\,mod\ n,\,$ allowing us to employ *Lagrange interpolation* to represent any finitary operation as a finite composition of the binary operations $\rm\, +,\ *,\,$ and $\rm\, \delta(a,b) = 1\,\ if\,\ a=b\,\ else\,\ 0,\ $ namely

$$\rm f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\ = \sum_{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\ \in\ A^n}\ f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\ \prod_{i\ =\ 1}^n\ \delta(x_i,a_i) $$

When $\rm\,|A|\,$ is infinite one may instead proceed by employing pairing functions $\rm\,A^2\to A.$

Comment: Thanks for the link to the earlier question. I see that @ZhenLin asks "So one might ask: does every algebraic theory  admit a presentation using only operations of arity at most 2? Unfortunately, I do not know the answer to this." If this were indeed the case, then would it be meaningful to say that mathematics exists outside any concept of time?