# Algebraic objects with non-binary operations

Tags: abstract-algebra

It seems that algebraists are particularly interested in sets equipped with binary operations that are well-behaved. I'm curious as to whether mathematicians have studied analogous structures equipped with non-binary operations. For example, why not have a set $G$ with some operation $\phi: G \times G \times G \to G$ such that $G$ is closed with respect to $\phi$? Granted, I'm not sure if the concept of an inverse can be maintained with a non-binary operation, (maybe associativity becomes non-sensical as well...?). Regardless, are there any interesting articles that address these kinds of questions?

Comment: This is (roughly) getting at operads.

Comment: There are some articles on Wikipedia: [Heap (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(mathematics)), [Median algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_algebra), [Principal homogeneous space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_homogeneous_space).

Comment: This is a FAQ - please see the linked dupe and its links.

Comment: https://www.kylem.net/papers/trinary_groups.pdf: This is the kind of thing I was looking for.

Comment: See also [Are all n-ary operators simply compositions of binary operators?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/116771/242)

Comment: @Calum Thanks for catching that. It was what I intended to use but I must have mistakenly touched a neighboring link in the search results. Now fixed.

Comment: (Cut-down version of my previous comment.) Another duplicate, already closed: [Why does abstract algebra have just binary functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3309601).